# Use NPM publish with Gitlab

Tags: npm, gitlab, npm-publish

I'd make my first `npm publish` into my Gitlab project. The project is private so I generated a deploy token with `read` & `write` permission for package registry.
Locally I created an .npmrc file and used these lines:

```
@laszlo-bottlik:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/28303714/packages/npm/
//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken='<deploy-name>:<deploy-password>'
//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/28303714/packages/npm/:_authToken='<deploy-name>:<deploy-password>'
```

Name value in package json is `@laszlo-bottlik/playground`
Url for the project is `https://gitlab.com/laszlo-bottlik/playground`

When I run `npm publish` command in terminal then I get 401 error:

```
HttpErrorGeneral: 401 Unauthorized - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/28303714/packages/npm/@laszlo-bottlik%2fplayground
```

Any kind of help can lead me to the solution.
What should I check in my local environment?
What should I check in my project settings under Gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using a deploy token as opposed to a job token? Either way, it looks like you may have an extra variable in your authToken argument above - You have `<deploy-name>:<deploy-password>` in your example code, but GitLab's code only shows a single auth_token argument ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#project-level-npm-endpoint)):

```
npm config set -- '//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<your_project_id>/packages/npm/:_authToken' "<your_token>"
```